# Convert time to number and then match it to a another number

Tags: excel, time, match

My problem is that I'd like to match time (hours) to a column with general numbers to get some values out from some other cells.

I managed to convert my date-time values to just the number of the hour using:

```
=TEXT(TIME(HOUR(B5),MINUTE(B5),SECOND(B5)),"h")
```

but when I try to match this to, for example, the number 10 it responds with `#N/A`.

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use HOUR function, that returns a number directly, e.g.

`=HOUR(B5)`

You can use that in a comparison or MATCH function, e.g.

`=IF(HOUR(B5)>10,"Late","Early")`

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to simply use:

```
=TEXT(B5,"h")
```

Now, the issue you're having is that `TEXT` returns a text value while you're probably looking up a number value. To convert the text value to a number value, you can multiply by 1 or add 0:

```
=TEXT(B5,"h")+0

=TEXT(B5,"h")*1
```

And that should do it!